# DevExpress WPF LayoutControl

Tags: wpf, devexpress

I was wondering if there is a way to add custom controls to the "New Elements" - section of LayoutControl in a similar way than adding controls to he AvailableItems - section.

Here´s my XAML-Code

```
<lc:LayoutControl 
                                x:Name="layoutItems" Orientation="Vertical" Background="Transparent" 
                                IsCustomization="True"
                                AllowItemMovingDuringCustomization="True"
                                AllowAvailableItemsDuringCustomization="True"
                                AllowItemRenamingDuringCustomization="True"
                                AllowItemSizingDuringCustomization="True">
        <lc:LayoutControl.AvailableItems>
            <lc:LayoutItem Label="TextFeld:">
                <dxe:TextEdit />
            </lc:LayoutItem>
            <lc:LayoutItem Label="LayoutItem 19:">
                <dxe:TextEdit />
            </lc:LayoutItem>
            <lc:LayoutItem Label="LayoutItem 20:">
                <dxe:TextEdit />
            </lc:LayoutItem>
            <lc:LayoutGroup View="GroupBox" Header="GroupBox 5" Orientation="Vertical">
                <lc:LayoutItem Label="LayoutItem 21:">
                    <dxe:TextEdit />
                </lc:LayoutItem>
                <lc:LayoutItem Label="LayoutItem 22:">
                    <dxe:TextEdit />
                </lc:LayoutItem>
                <lc:LayoutItem Label="LayoutItem 23:">
                    <dxe:TextEdit />
                </lc:LayoutItem>
            </lc:LayoutGroup>
        </lc:LayoutControl.AvailableItems>

    </lc:LayoutControl>
```